# Is the Break keyword the most efficent way to exit a for loop? C/C++

Tags: c++, c, loops

Is break the most efficient way to exit a loop? In the code snippet below, would line A or line B be the more efficient way to exit the loop? Any links to material on how the break instruction works under the hood would be appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       cout << i << endl;
       if (i == 3) {
           break;  // A
           i = 15; // B
       }
   }
```

I assume the difference is trivial in most situations, and that A is faster because B requires an assignment, an increment, and then a comparison, but I don't actually know how break works and it's better to know than assume. Thanks!

Comment: Since the results are obiviously similar, it's up to the compiler. Please measure yourself, if you need, but if you don't really need, use the clearest code and let the optimizer worry for performance.

Comment: If two pieces of code have exactly the same observable effects (which is true in your example) then the compiler is free to transform one version into the other version, or to transform both into a different version. So your question is meaningless in any generic sense. All you can do is try both versions on your favourite compiler and see what happens.

Comment: Compile both versions *with* optimizations *enabled* and measure (and inspect the generated assembly). I doubt there will be any noticeable difference after the optimizer has done its job.

Comment: I think that too many new programmers believe that the code they write is exactly the same code that is run, in terms of assembly language.  That is not the case -- the code you write is just a description of what you want to happen -- the compiler can then do anything to the code to turn it into something completely different than what you expect, but still at the end get the job done as described by the program.  If you want proof, try to debug an optimized program -- you will see the "current line" jump all over the place when stepping through the code, variables totally eliminated, etc.

Comment: That sounds like me :^). I want to learn to write efficient code but am just getting started so don't quite know where to look yet. Point taken about the optimiser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's compile the following code and look at the assembly:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int loop_with_break() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        puts("Hello, world!");
        if (i == 3) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

int loop_with_assignment() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i ++) {
        puts("Hello, world!");
        if (i == 3) {
            i = 10;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    loop_with_break();
    loop_with_assignment();
}
```

[image: assembly of loop with break]
[image: assembly of loop with assignment]
As you can see, when you use `break`, if `i == 3`, it'll jump straight out of the loop to the end of the function, whereas if you use `i = 10`, it'll set `i` to 10, increment it by 1, then do the comparison, which is slower. However, this was compiled with no optimizations. If you use optimizations, they both end up becoming the same thing. However, since `break` is more readable and these optimizations are not guaranteed, you should use it for breaking out of loops.

Comment: Thanks! This is really clear. By the way, how did you get these diagrams? I'm a new coder and am interested in efficiency and optimization but don't know where to get started. Any resources you could point me to would be much appreciated.

Comment: These diagrams are known as call graphs, and I'm generating them with Binary Ninja, which is unfortunately a paid product. However, [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/) is a great site to explore the assembly that your code generates.

Answer (score 4):

The keyword `break` will just quit the loop without any comparison made in the loop condition. If you use `i = 15` syntax, the loop will iterate next time to verify whether the variable `i` is greater than 10, if so, then quit.

In short words, `break` will break the loop without thinking anything, whereas `i = 15` will lead one more iteration to look if the condition satisfies it.

Answer (score 1):

You're right! Actually `break` keyword is very faster for breaking loop!

In your example, if you use line A, then as soon as control reaches this statement, it will immediately break the loop.

On the other hand, if you use line B, then first the assignment will be performed and again the control will go to the condition checking and when the condition will get false then it will exit from the loop!

Answer (score 0):

if you choose while loop you can prefer to make condition false in the while loop. But in this case using break make sense.

Comment: The same (loop condition) can be said of a for loop. There is really no difference in this regard. Also this is not a question of preference. If the break condition arises within the loop body then using the loops condition instead becomes quite cumbersome.